Binary Search Implementation with ceil in wikipedia
On Wikipedia, I see this alternative implementation of binary search:

function binary_search_alternative(A, n, T) is
    L := 0
    R := n − 1
    while L != R do
        m := ceil((L + R) / 2)
        if A[m] > T then
            R := m − 1
        else:
            L := m
    if A[L] = T then
        return L
    return unsuccessful


Is there any relation between the ceil function that is used for calculating the middle index and that M is assigned to L and not M + 1? The latter is what I find in the standard implementation of binary search, where the middle index is found with integer division.

Please do not post a link to a painting of the code! You can [edit] your question to include the code as formatted text.


Is there any relation between the ceil function that is used for calculating the middle index and that M is assigned to L and not M + 1?

Yes, there is a relation. More often the floor function is used, or similarly, an integer division operator. And in that case L or M are updated differently. If we would rewrite the code you quoted to use floor, then it could look like this
Version using floor:
function binary_search_alternative(A, n, T) is
    L := 0
    R := n − 1
    while L != R do
        m := floor((L + R) / 2)
        if A[m] < T then
            L := m + 1
        else:
            R := m
    if A[L] = T then
        return L
    return unsuccessful

The body of the loop is different compared to the code you quoted, which I provide here again:
Version using ceil:
function binary_search_alternative(A, n, T) is
    L := 0
    R := n − 1
    while L != R do
        m := ceil((L + R) / 2)
        if A[m] > T then
            R := m − 1
        else:
            L := m
    if A[L] = T then
        return L
    return unsuccessful

There are at least two things to pay attention to:

The block that gets executed when T would be equal to A[m] should assign m to one of the boundaries of the window, not m+1 or m-1, as that would exclude the potentially matching value from the window. In the code you quoted, the else block is executed when there is equality, so it would be wrong to have there L := m + 1.

We cannot assign m in both if and else block, as that could lead to an infinite loop. This is because you must ensure that the window becomes smaller at each iteration: this must be guaranteed. A good test to pay attention to is when L and R differ by one unit.
In that case the ceil function will return the value of R, while the floor function will return the value of L. If we have m == R (the ceil version) then you when you make an assignment to R you must ensure it is less than R, i.e. it should get the value m - 1 and not m. While if we have m == L (the floor version), then we should assign L := m + 1 instead of L := m.


Note how these two versions really mirror each other: R and L are swapped, the comparison operator is toggled (< versus >) and - 1 and + 1 mirror each other. This corresponds how floor and ceil mirror each other.
We could also have altered the statements after the loop to complete the mirror perfectly, and replace L with R in that part of the code, but as these two variables are equal when A is not empty, it doesn't really matter.
The function should really include a check whether A is empty, as we don't want to evaluate A[L] in that case nor even end up inside the loop. So in both cases the function should better have this at the top:
    if n = 0 then
        return unsuccessful

